# What is the equivalent of Linux's (bashe's actually) “&>” in Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd.exe

How can I redirect (to one file) stdin and stderr of the program? I look for something like `&>` in bash for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following syntax:

```
your_command > log.txt 2>&1
```

This redirects `STDOUT` to log.txt and `STDERR` to `STDOUT` resulting into all output being logged in log.txt

By the way, this syntax is valid in both: Windows and Linux

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses a similar syntax, as [described here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

> `command > file 2>&1`       Redirect errors and output to one file